# Is there a way to forcably disconnect a remote rdp user, or to forceably stop vrde

Tags: virtualbox

I have a virtualbox server running in windows 10.
We are using the built in remote desktop server to allow multiple users to log in. this allows for a nice collaborative working environment. Is there a way to forceably disconnect a remote user , or even stop the remote desktop service.

Ive tried vboxmanage but it mostly just complains the session is locked. like below.

C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox>VBoxManage modifyvm "ubuntu_20_LTS" --vrdemulticon off

VBoxManage.exe: error: The machine 'ubuntu_20_LTS' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)

VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown

VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 554 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp

Answer (score 1):

```
VBoxManage controlvm VMname vrde off
sleep 1
VBoxManage controlvm VMname vrde on
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this can be done.
From the running machine using the normal virtualbox display . type host+f until you see the virtualbox menu. then select view->remote display. This will disconnect any active virtualbox RDP sessions to the client machine.